# Correct way to set up a DDP model in a Thread

Tags: python, pytorch, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, multi-gpu

I want to train a DDP model from within a thread. Currently, the thread is created as:

```py
t1 = threading.Thread(target=training_func, name='target')
t1.start()
```

where `training_func` is where the DDP model should be created. The DDP model is handled by Pytorch Lightning code. However, my function hangs at the initialisation of DDP process:

```bash
Initializing distributed: GLOBAL_RANK: 0, MEMBER: 1/2
host:3886:3998 [1] NCCL INFO P2P is disabled between connected GPUs 0 and 1. You can repress this message with NCCL_IGNORE_DISABLED_P2P=1.
host:3886:3998 [1] NCCL INFO Could not enable P2P between dev 0(=3000) and dev 1(=88000)
host:3812:3996 [0] NCCL INFO P2P is disabled between connected GPUs 1 and 0. You can repress this message with NCCL_IGNORE_DISABLED_P2P=1.
```

I tried using a Pytorch Lightning Trainer, using Pytorch with DDP via `dist.init_process_group` but it fails as well. I also attempted to change the backend to gloo from nccl but the problem persists.
Even other libraries seem to have this issue. I attempted the same code with Ray and Huggingface and had the same issue, maybe because they also use Pytorch code underneath for distributed training.

I expected the thread to use the available GPUs to initialize the model correctly.

What is the right way to allocate gpu resources to a thread?

Comment: "I want to train a DDP model from within a thread." – Why?

Comment: Hyperparameter tuning of the model. It's a large model so a single GPU won't do.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you need threads there.

Comment: In Python, a "thread" is a line of execution by a single processor.  To employ multiple processors or cores, you need to use Python multiprocessing.  Probably you need Processes here, not Threads.

Comment: @PaulCornelius That's not true. Threads in Python are real OS threads and may be executed by different cores/processors, it's just that due to the GIL only a single thread will be executing _Python_ code at a time. That doesn't help OP, though; they'd have to refer to Pytorch's manual to figure out how to distribute training work across GPU devices.

Comment: @AKX, I wanted to use the Pytorch Lightning code to handle the actual distributed training part. Would it still be possible or would I have to shift to another library? My goal is to start multiple DDP processes at the same time.

Comment: @DiptiSengupta I'm not following. If your goal is to start multiple processes, _start multiple processes_, don't faff around with threads.

Comment: @AKX. Unfortunately, the library I have to use makes use of the thread calls I put in my post. I was hoping to use them. But thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: What library is that? This really sounds pretty weird.

Comment: @AKX HpBandStr. It's a library for hyperparameter optimisation. In theory, it should work for DDP cases as well.

Comment: @DiptiSengupta https://github.com/automl/HpBandSter/tree/master ? Seems it's unmaintained, I wouldn't use it.